# Concat multiple small DataFrames as one big DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make  a   large  DataFrame   from a bunch of  smaller  DF. so  I've look at multiple  sites a nd  they all  mention  to use the `pd.concat()` method  and create  an empty DataFrame.  I did, however when I print  inside  my for loop I  still get  data  as  if  it was still  sectioned  by  individual DataFrame,  and  when i  print  my (now  supposedly  filled DataFrame )   I get an  empty  DF.

Note:  All  tables  have the  same  structure

```
import camelot
import pandas as pd


# GETS  73 tables 
pdf_data = camelot.read_pdf('GMCC services 8517404.pdf', flavor='lattice', pages='1', encoding='utf-8' )
all_data = pd.DataFrame()


for info  in pdf_data:

    df= info.df
    # GETTABLE IN  DATAFRAME
    # df = info.df

  # concatenate alltables in one  dataframe 
    # all_data = pd.concat([all_data, df.reset_index(drop=True)])
    master = pd.concat([all_data, df.reset_index(drop=True)])
       
    # CHANGE  COLUMN NAMES  FOR   REAL DATA 
    master = master.rename({0:'product_no',1:'description', 2:'quantity', 3:'net_price', 4:'total'}, axis='columns')

    # GET  SITECODE 
    site = master.iloc[-1, 0]

    # GET FIRST ROW && DROP FIRST ROW  OF EVERY TABLE
    master = master.reindex(master.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True)

    # # CREATE  COLUMN  SITE  WITH  SITE CODE
    master['site'] = site

    # Drop LAst ROW on EVERY TABLE
    master.drop(index=master.index[-1], 
        axis=0, 
        inplace=True)

    #    # concatenate alltables in one  dataframe 
    #     all_data = pd.concat([all_data, df.reset_index(drop=True)]) 

    print(master)
# services = all_data.groupby('description')
# unique_sevices = services.apply(lambda x: x['net_price'].unique())


# print(unique_sevices)
```

what I'm  currently  getting:

```
 product_no    |    description     |    quantity    |  net_price    |    site    | 
0 11223        |    Gen desc. 1     |        5       |      19       |    USCA    |
1 22334        |    Gen desc. 2     |        11      |      15       |    USCA    |

 product_no    |    description     |    quantity    |  net_price    |    site    |
0 55667        |    Gen desc. 5     |        10      |      15       |    USNY    |
1 22334        |    Gen desc. 2     |        3       |      11       |    USNY    |
```

What I  want:

```
 product_no    |    description     |    quantity    |  net_price    |    site    | 
0 11223        |    Gen desc. 1     |        5       |      19       |    USCA    |
1 22334        |    Gen desc. 2     |        11      |      15       |    USCA    |
2 55667        |    Gen desc. 5     |        10      |      15       |    USNY    |
3 22334        |    Gen desc. 2     |        3       |      11       |    USNY    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
all_data = pd.concat([t.df for t in pdf_data], ignore_index=True)
```

If you want to loop and modify your data, you can collect them all in a list and use `concat` after the loop:

```
list_of_df = list()
for table in pdf_data:
    df = table.df.rename({0:'product_no',1:'description', 2:'quantity', 3:'net_price', 4:'total'}, axis=1)
    df["site"] = df.iat[-1, 0]
    df = df[1:-1]
    list_of_df.append(df)

master = pd.concat(list_of_df, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks!  this  in fact does create  a   larger  DataFrame ... but how  can I  put  the data  after the  modifications  I made   before  concatenating   them ?

Comment: lol. the ones I tried to make inside my for loop,  remove  first line of every small DataFrame, getting the  first Column of the  last row  as 'site'  and  adding a  new  column  as site with that info, and  removing that last  row.   so basically I wanted to  append  after all those modifications.

Comment: @victorR - It's very difficult to guess without having an actual sample of some of the DataFrames you have (before modifications). But I've edited my answer. If that doesn't work, edit the OP to include some examples. For example `pdf_data[0].df.to_dict()` and `pdf_data[1].df.to_dict()`